# ComboBox action results with exception

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, white-framework

I have this app that I need to write some automation for it.
See image for data of that app.
I'm using White / TestStack and C# and VS2015.

I'm trying to capture / get the combobox control (see image) and to set a value to it using the `ComboBox.click()` or `Combobox.Select()` methods.
It looks like I can get the object but when I write in my code `ComboBox.click()` or `Combobox.Select(1)` it results with "system.invalidoperationexception" exception.

Note - if I write `combobox.Click()` in the "Watch" window of the VS2015 the action is performed, But if I write `combobox.Select(1)` I get an error.

below is my code for getting the combobox object.

```
public static bool ComboBoxByAutomationID(ref TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window win, ref 
TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ComboBox comboBox, String AutoId)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nofRetries; i++)
        {
            if (win.Exists<TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ComboBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId(AutoId)))
            {
                comboBox = win.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ComboBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId(AutoId));
                mGenLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ": Found " + AutoId + "[loop: " + i + "]");
                return true;
            }
            mGenLog.Debug(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ": NOT Found " + AutoId + "[loop: " + i + "]");
        }
        mMainLog.Error(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ": NOT Found " + AutoId + "[loop: " + nofRetries + "]");
        return false;
    }
```

So, just before the "return true" I added:

```
comboBox.Click();  
comboBox.Select(1);
```

And still I got an exception.

App Data:

[image: App Data]

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled  HResult=-2146233079 
>    Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. Source=Interop.UIAutomationClient  StackTrace: at UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement.SetFocus() at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.SetFocus() in d:\dev\UIAComWrapper\UiaComWrapper\AutomationElement.cs:line 455 at TestStack.White.UIItems.UIItem.Focus() in C:\projects\white-9yaco\src\TestStack.White\UIItems\UIItem.c‌​s:line 301 InnerException:

Comment: If you get an error, you should always post the full error message and call stack with the question.

Comment: Exception details:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  Source=Interop.UIAutomationClient
  StackTrace:
       at UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement.SetFocus()
       at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.SetFocus() in d:\dev\UIAComWrapper\UiaComWrapper\AutomationElement.cs:line 455
       at TestStack.White.UIItems.UIItem.Focus() in C:\projects\white-9yaco\src\TestStack.White\UIItems\UIItem.cs:line 301
  InnerException:

Comment: So, which of the code lines in the question is `AutomationElement.cs:line 455` and which one is `UIItem.c‌​s:line 301`?

Comment: d:\dev\UIAComWrapper\UiaComWrapper\AutomationElement.cs:line 455 is part of the .Net and Visual studio.

\TestStack.White\UIItems\UIItem.c‌​s:line 301 is part of the White framework that I'm using.

The code above calls/ uses the 'white' code

Comment: So basically *some unknown event* is triggering the execution of *whatever* in `UIItem.c‌​s:line 301` and this happens irregardless of `comboBox.Click(); comboBox.Select(1);` (meaning, you tried those, but in the end they turn out to be irrelevant to the problem). At least that's what I read from the question, because you are not completely specific on where and when which error occurs.

Comment: I do think that the comboBox.Click(); comboBox.Select(1); triggers the exception, if those commands are not excuted, then there is no exception.

Comment: 2nd paragraph *"but when I write in my code ComboBox.click() or Combobox.Select(1) it results with "system.invalidoperationexception" exception."* where did you write the code and if both statements are problematic, please check the resulting error for each of them separately - is it the same error? What is the error for `combobox.Select(1)` in the watch window? Way below in your question *"... And still I got an exception."* again... is it the same exception or a different one? Does the exception occur while executing the `Click`, the `Select` or does it occur later?

Comment: OK. maybe I was not clear.
If the function (in the code above) stay as is => no Error.
But when I add in the code(!) comboBox.Click() [Just before the 'return true'] then I get an exception as detailed above. But if I debug and stop before the 'return true' and write in the watch window, then the action is executed.
If I do the same with comboBox.Select(1) then on both the watch and code I get the exception.
The exception is the same on both cases.
Thanks

Comment: As commented, your exception doesn't really reflect this... if the exception is raised on `Click` and you provide full exception information, then I expect `Click` to be on the call stack. But the call stack you provided ends in `Focus`... maybe there is an inner exception or some other attached information that's not yet in the question?